# What is the use of '& .MuiTextField-root' in { makeStyles } of Material UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am making a project in React JS through some resources using Material-UI. I was creating  in Form.js file for my app, and there was some styling given to that  as shown below ---

````
 import useStyles from './styles';
 const classes = useStyles();

<form autoCapitalize='off' noValidate className={`${classes.root} ${classes.form}`} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>  ```
````

In styles.js --

```
export default makeStyles((theme) => ({
    
     root: {
     '& .MuiTextField-root': {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
    },
  },
    form: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }

}));
```

Now I am not able to understand the use of

```
     '& .MuiTextField-root': {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
    }
```

Can anyone please help me with this like what is the use of '& .MuiTextField-root' ??

When I try to simply use the

`margin: theme.spacing(1)`,

its not giving margin from top and bottom, but its giving very less margin
from left and right. But using the Former one gives equal and more margin
from each side to all the textfields and Buttons in the . Why is it so??   Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Attaching the Screenshot ---[FORM Image with `'& .MuiTextField-root'`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsmjd.png)

[FORM Image WithOut '& .MuiTextField-root', just using `root: {margin: theme.spacing(1)}` only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhPfD.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know `SCSS` then this is the convention to select the child selector to write class for. As you are using it in a form. So the text fields are the child of the form. That's why you have to access/write it like this.

The following code actually mean, any child containing the class name `MuiTextField-root` will have the `margin` css rules in it. [Doc](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/)

```
'& .MuiTextField-root': {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

& .MuiTextField-root would mean any children of current element with that class

Answer (score 1):

You can use the browser dev tools to identify the slot for the component you want to override. It can save you a lot of time. The styles injected into the DOM by MUI rely on class names that follow a simple pattern: [hash]-Mui[Component name]-[name of the slot].

⚠️ These class names can't be used as CSS selectors because they are unstable, however, MUI applies global class names using a consistent convention: Mui[Component name]-[name of the slot].

If you would like to override the styles of the components using classes, you can use the className prop available on each component. For overriding the styles of the different parts inside the component, you can use the global classes available for each slot, as described in the previous section.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Brother, I will surely use this to save my time, though I am already using Firefox Dev Tools for styling purposes and Chrome Redux Dev Tools for the actions and reducers, MUI is somewhat new to me, so this suggestion will help me a lot !  Thanks again 